# 'vsce' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." after npm i -g @vscode/vsce"

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm, vscode-extensions

i have just installed vsce using `npm install -g @vscode/vsce` but after successfully installing cmd is showing this error :
'vsce' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

i have run cmd with administrator because when i try to install without administrator it's showing this error:

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vscode\.vsce-q9bFjg86
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vscode\.vsce-q9bFjg86'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vscode\.vsce-q9bFjg86'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@vscode\\.vsce-q9bFjg86'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ChetanKK\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-05T05_06_01_324Z-debug-0.log
```

i want to publish my vscode theme on marketplace

Comment: try this npm i --save-dev @vscode/vsce

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i've found that your computer's use shuld be administrator for running this command
i'm trying this on other local account but this is fixed by running this command on administrator account